# Read the excel file that is added as the resource in the WFA in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing a game in Visual Studio 2008, C# Windows Forms Application. It is a word game. For that I read set of words from excel file named "Dictionary.xlsx".

```
      `Excel.Application ExcelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
       Excel.Workbook theWorkbook;
       Excel.Sheets sheets;
       Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
       public Excel.Range range;
       string str;

       //in the load event of the form
       theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Dictionary.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;
        worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
        range = worksheet.UsedRange;

        //reading the contents from excel file and adding into ListBox "listBox1" 
        for (int rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
        {
            str1 = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
            listBox1.Items.Add(str1.ToUpper());  
        }`
```

This "Dictionary.xlsx" contains 51899 words. So it takes 5 minutes to read the contents into a ListBox "listBox1".
So I added that "Dictionary.xlsx" file into my application's Resource by right clicking Resources->Add->Existing item->Dictionary.xlsx in the Solution Explorer. When I searched, I came to know that the key to access resource files is to use `ResourceManager` class from `System.Resources` namespace.
 But I have no idea about how to instantiate `ResourceManager` class. When I looked at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I can't understand it.
 **Now how can I read or refer to the words in my dictionary in my project resource?
Does reading from Resource file take less time than reading from external file?**

Thank you:-)..

Comment: Do you *really* need to use Excel for this? The interop is probably whats taking all the time and you might be better off with a csv file (which can be opened in Excel easily) and can be parsed quickly without needing Excel. You'll also remove the requirement that your users have Excel installed.

Comment: `I am developing a game in Visual Studio 2008, C# Windows Forms Application.` - winforms is not a suitable platform for games (nor for anything else I can think of). If your UI is simple, you should use WPF, otherwise look at XNA or MonoGame or Unity3D.

Comment: `it takes 5 minutes to read the contents into a ListBox` - You might want to have a look at [this short clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA)

Comment: @HighCore: Winforms can certainly be used for certain types of games, although WPF is better in pretty much every way. It's pretty clear the OP isn't trying to create Half Life 3 here.

Comment: @MattBurland `Winforms can certainly be used for certain types of games` - the same can be said about COBOL or Quick Basic, however NO sane person would lose any time creating any new software projects using these **obsolete** technologies, in 2014.

Comment: @HighCore: And no sane person would create a simple word game in Unity3D either.

Comment: Thank you @MattBurland :-D:-D.. Now I use .txt file. I loads entire words within 2 seconds!:-D.. thanks a lot:-D..

Comment: Thank you @Grant Winney :-D:-D.. Now I use .txt file. I loads entire words within 2 seconds!:-D.. thanks a lot:-D..